# Count consecutive ocurrences SQL - Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Reposting because some postgres functions are not available on Amazon Redshift.

I am trying to count the number of consecutive weeks an employee went to work. So I have this table that has whether jon or andy went to work on certain weeks (I have all week of the year).

I am trying on Redshift

Input table

[image: Input table]

What I would like know the number of times each person went consecutively to work x number of weeks.

So the way the below is read is that Andy went twice two consecutive weeks.

Output Table

[image: Output table]

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a code writing service.  If you want that you should hire a consultant.  If you want our help you need to show what you did that did not work -- we help people get un-stuck when they have come to an impase.  Please show what you have tried -- or even better the code you know works on another system and then what functions don't work on this system (as you suggested at the start.)  Then you can expect to get an answer and not closed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the chance of trying this query in Redshift, so I ran it in PostgreSQL instead. I'm guessing the functions in it are generic enough to run in Redshift without issues.

```
select person, consecutive_weeks, count(*) as times
from (
  select person, g, count(*) as consecutive_weeks
  from (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by person order by week) -
      sum(went_to_work) over (partition by person order by week) as g
    from t
  ) x
  where went_to_work <> 0
  group by person, g
) y
group by person, consecutive_weeks
order by person, consecutive_weeks
```

Result:

```
 person  consecutive_weeks  times 
 ------- ------------------ ----- 
 andy    2                  2     
 john    2                  1     
 john    3                  1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-N3Fo77J).